# portable mp4 audio extractor

Tags: uwp, mp4, portable-class-library, data-conversion

I'm struggling to find a simple audio extractor from a mp4 file which preferably runs in portable libraries or in UWP applications.

I know about ffmpeg, and I've even found a Win10 Interop version: https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop.
But (at a first glance) this library is very complex to include & use, and I have not found an example where they actually use the conversion features of ffmpeg. Also, I would prefer a portable version.

I'm looking for something as easy as I've found for .flv files (and as used in https://github.com/famoser/YoutubeExtractor.Portable, this library only uses one single class for this task!).

If someone could point me into the right direction on how to do this myself for mp4, or even better, if there already exists a library for this task, I'd be thankful.